# The wp-admin is redirecting to sub domain

Tags: php, wordpress

Here is the site http://jbcommodity.com/ . When I go to wp-admin it redirects to http://jbcommodity.onlineprestigemanagement.com/wp-admin/ . I don't understand what's causing this. On site URL everything is OK.
If I go to http://jbcommodity.com/login I get a blank white page.

Answer (score 0):

If http://jbcommodity.onlineprestigemanagement.com/wp-admin/  isn't accessible

**solution 1**

add those lines in wp-config.php

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

**solution 2**

In database change values for siteurl and home in option table.

**solution 3**

**If site is still accessible** on http://jbcommodity.onlineprestigemanagement.com/wp-admin/ simply go to Settings -> general and change the values there.

**solution 4**

Using wp-cli http://wp-cli.org/ (this require a ssh access ant that wp-cli is correctly installed, bu this is the only solution that will fix all url in wordpress

```
wp search-replace 'example.dev' 'example.com' --skip-columns=guid
```

**Solutions [...]**

There are some more solutions here 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

Comment: i have tried all 3.the result is same,one more thing i noticed that on my site the subtitle text is something but on database wp-option  its showing  My WordPress Blog.i ll try 4th one

Comment: Have you checked that it isn't set in your theme function.php ?

Comment: Using wp-cli in your case you might prefer not to use the option --skip-columns=guid assuming you want all to work and appear as http://jbcommodity.com/